# How to set GAE_SDK_ROOT environment variable?

Tags: linux, google-app-engine, environment-variables

I am trying to run a Google app locally on `Ubuntu`, but when I run `dev_appserver.py` I get this error:

```
ValueError: Could not determine SDK root; please set GAE_SDK_ROOT environment variable.
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: How are you running dev_appserver.py and where do you have everything (GAE SDK files) stored (structured)? I have all my GAE files in /usr/local/gae and I run stuff from some dir by running > /usr/local/gae/dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=/usr/bin/php5-cgi . (where that final period refers to whatever directory my project is in). Also, I've never set, and don't seem to have GAE_SDK_ROOT as an env variable (Ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: GAE files are in a directory in Home, called google_appengine. Also in home I have my app, named myapp. I am running > google_appengine/dev_appserver.py myapp/ and I get that error.

Comment: Where are you specifying the PHP executable path? Are you?

Comment: No, i am not, is it necessary?

Comment: I did it with Robin Green's idea and it finally worked. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @rodrigo-silveira GAE is available for Python and Java as well as PHP - in fact PHP is the newcomer to the party.

Comment: Ah, of course... I don't know why I assumed you were running the PHP runtime - maybe because that's what I'm using, and I do encounter undocumented issues from time to time... I'm glad you got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export GAE_SDK_ROOT= wherever you unzipped the Google App Engine SDK
```

Comment: Like this : export GAE_SDK_ROOT= Home/google_appengine/ ?? It doesn't work... (I am just starting with ubuntu, sorry...)

Comment: Almost - the home environment variable is referred to as `$HOME`, not `Home`. Also, no space after the = (sorry, my answer was misleading).

Comment: Thanks! I am still having an error, now it tells me ValueError: GAE_SDK_ROOT '/home/ubuntu/google_appengine' does not refer to a valid SDK directory

Comment: api_server.py           dev_appserver.py      LICENSE
appcfg.py               download_appstats.py  _php_runtime.py
backends_conversion.py  endpointscfg.py       _python_runtime.py
BUGS                    gen_protorpc.py       README
bulkload_client.py      google                RELEASE_NOTES
bulkloader.py           google_sql.py         VERSION
demos                   lib

Comment: Yes, it does. Maybe it got corrupted somehow and maybe you just need to delete it and unzip it again.

Comment: @mcaceresm OK, please accept my answer - that will mark the question as closed and help future visitors to home in on the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `~/.profile`:

```
export CLOUDSDK_ROOT_DIR="/path/to/google/cloud/sdk/"
export APPENGINE_HOME="${CLOUDSDK_ROOT_DIR}/platform/appengine-java-sdk"
export GAE_SDK_ROOT="${CLOUDSDK_ROOT_DIR}/platform/google_appengine"

# The next line enables Java libraries for Google Cloud SDK
export CLASSPATH="${APPENGINE_HOME}/lib":${CLASSPATH}

# The next line enables Python libraries for Google Cloud SDK
export PYTHONPATH=${GAE_SDK_ROOT}:${PYTHONPATH}
```